# Convert a Tree to SemanticGraph in Stanford parser

Tags: parsing, stanford-nlp

I want to covert a Tree to SemanticGraph in Stanford Parser as followings:

```
LexicalizedParser lp  = LexicalizedParser.loadModel("edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz");
LexicalizedParserQuery lpq=lp.lexicalizedParserQuery();

String sentence="This is a sentence.";

List<CoreLabel> tokenizedSentence = tokenizerFactory.getTokenizer(new StringReader(sentence)).tokenize();
lpq.parse(tokenizedSentence);
Tree depTree = lpq.getBestParse();
SemanticGraph semanticGraph = ParserAnnotatorUtils.generateUncollapsedDependencies(depTree);
```

`ParserAnnotatorUtils.generateUncollapsedDependencies(depTree)` works on version 2.0.4. But it does not work on Version 3.5.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
Tree tree = ...
GrammaticalStructureFactory gsf = new UniversalEnglishGrammaticalStructureFactory();
SemanticGraph dependencyGraph = SemanticGraphFactory.generateCollapsedDependencies( gsf.newGrammaticalStructure(tree), GrammaticalStructure.Extras.NONE );
```